# Python - List element to provide dictionary name

Tags: python-3.x

I am thinking I want use a list with business sections to do the following:

```
accounting = {'regex' : 'blah|something', 'filename' : 'somefile' }
print(accounting['regex']) # results in 'blah|something'

business = ['accounting', 'it', 'security']

for each in business:
    rx = each['regex']`
```

I'm clearly missing something obvious here.  The idea is to tie the list item to a dictionary with the same name for later processing.  Newbie...sorry.

I get this:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'  indicating that this is being interpreted as a list reference.

Comment: `business = ['accounting', 'it', 'security']` is just a list of strings; your dictionaries have absolutely nothing to do with this.  Without those quote marks, it would be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: You're confusing variable names with strings. accounting, the variable, is not same as "accounting" the string

Comment: What I want to do is use the list elements to call a dictionary by the same name so I can pull items from that dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question requieres more clarity, but I can assume something like this:

You have three dictionaries:

```
accounting = {'regex' : 'blah|something', 'filename' : 'somefile' }
it = {'regex': r'bar|baz', 'filename': 'othwefild'}
security = {'regex': r'bar|baz', 'filename': 'othwefild'}
```

(Notice the prefix `r` for the regexes... It's a good practice do treat regexes as raw strings)

Then you can define your list:

```
business = [accounting, it, security]
```

Notice that each element of your list is a variable.

And now you can iterate over the list and get the regex:

```
for each in business:
    rx = each['regex']
```

---

Of course, if you want to actually _do something with the regex, you need to import the `re` module:

```
import re
# ...
for each in business:
    rx = each['regex']
    # for example:
    regex = re.compile(rx)
    # Use the regex
```

I recommend you take a look to the official [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

---

**Edit**

Test run (python 3.11.3 CLI):

```
>>> accounting = {'regex' : 'blah|something', 'filename' : 'somefile' }
>>> it = {'regex': r'bar|baz', 'filename': 'othwefild'}
>>> security = {'regex': r'bar|baz', 'filename': 'othwefild'}
>>> business = [accounting, it, security]
>>> for each in business:
...     rx = each['regex']
...     print(rx)
...
blah|something
bar|baz
bar|baz
```

Comment: You are exactly correct in your assumptions but I get the following error in the for loop:
    rx = each['regex']
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: @fjr1300: You ignored the part of the answer which told you to switch from `business = ['accounting', 'it', 'security']` (a `list` of `str`) to `business = [accounting, it, security]` (a `list` of whatever objects are bound to those three variable names, presumably `dict`s).

Comment: Check the edit: I tested it on python she'll... You should really take a good refresher on the official tutorial

Comment: Facepalm: I had single quotes around each of the list items.  Thanks for your help and patience.

Yes, I'm working through Python training, too

Comment: But how would you create/init dictionaries using the items of a list?

Comment: @fjr1300 if you have a new question, post it... However, studying the tutorials you can get to the answer yourself.